# embedded derby starts with J2C error

Tags: java, websphere, derby

I create a datasource as

```
    @DataSourceDefinition
(
  name="java:app/env/myDataSource",
  className="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource40",
  databaseName="myDB",
  properties=
  {
    // Vendor properties for Derby Embedded JDBC driver:
    "createDatabase=create",
    "connectionAttributes=upgrade=true",

    // Custom properties for WebSphere Application Server:
    "connectionTimeout=60",
    "dataStoreHelperClass=com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DerbyDataStoreHelper",
    "validateNewConnection=true",
    "validateNewConnectionRetryCount=5"
  },
  serverName=""
)
```

Then I put it into the startup code.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartUp {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/env/myDataSource")
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;
...
```

When websphere server starts up, I got the below error and more

> [12/12/16 15:05:28:136 EST] 0000003b J2CXAResource W   J2CA0061W:
>   Error creating XA Connection and Resource java.lang.Exception:
>   Parameter xaResInfo lacks an RA wrapper and an RA wrapper could not be
>   resolved using RA key.    at
>   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CXAResourceFactory$1.run(J2CXAResourceFactory.java:264)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.j2c.J2CXAResourceFactory.getXAResource(J2CXAResourceFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.getXARminst(XARecoveryData.java:492)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.XARecoveryData.recover(XARecoveryData.java:658)
>     at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.PartnerLogTable.recover(PartnerLogTable.java:432)
>     at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.resync(RecoveryManager.java:1543)
>     at
>   com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:2276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RecoveryManager.performResync(RecoveryManager.java:119)
>     at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RecoveryManager.run(RecoveryManager.java:2229)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)

Any thought? I think the embedded derby doesn't need the J2C.

Comment: is this WebSphere traditional or Liberty?  I tried out this exact setup on Liberty and it worked fine.  Do you want XA capabilities?  If not, you could simply downgrade to a non-XA data source, for example: `className = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource40"`

Comment: @aguibert It's traditional. It should work as it worked before. But all of sudden, when I start the server today, it gives the error. I wonder what's going on? Yes, I need xa.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but the server is trying to perform XA recovery which is failing.  What version of WAS are you running?  I found the exact error message you are seeing but it looks like it was fixed in WAS 7.0 (circa 2011) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014284573

Comment: My version is WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aguibert said, the server is attempting to perform XA recovery, which is failing. Here's a link with info about recovering from a failed recovery:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/recovering_from_failed_transaction_recovery_websphere_application_server?lang=en

> **In cases where the logged transaction is of no concern**, you can simply stop the application server, navigate to the tranlog and partnerlog directories and delete the contents (log1 & log2) of both directories, then restart the app server.
>
> For reference, unless changed by your configuration, the default directories are typically located in the paths:
>
> C:WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\tranlog\MyNode01Cell\MyNode02\server1\transaction\partnerlog\
>
> C:WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\tranlog\MyNode01Cell\MyNode02\server1\transaction\tranlog\

Comment: You nailed it. It probably caused by that I didn't shut down the eclipse properly earlier.

Comment: That would definitely do it. I've lost workspaces before because I didn't shut down eclipse properly.